# java saving 2d array as an object in genetic algorithm

Tags: java, genetic-algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have been working on a multi-objective optimization problem which uses a genetic algorithm to display the best solution for over a year now.

The problem involves assigning people to different teams according to a number of criteria. I have already completed the initialisation stage and the fitness function coding is completed as well. However, I am having trouble saving the generated (2d array) solutions as objects and keep them in memory temporarily so that they can be used in later stages of GA: Selection, Crossover and Mutation.

I am using the roulette-wheel selection and slightly different crossover and mutation algorithms. I don't have a problem with these. It's just that I have not been able to find a way to save 1 generated solution (in this case complete team allocation) in memory temporarily and then generate another solution and keep that in memory and then another and so on.

I have tried quite a lot of different things that i could think of, from which two that I can remember are: 
(i) changed the 2d array type from int to Object but this gave an error as the 2d array that creates teams uses another int array to locate person id index position in the list; 
(ii) using static class field variable which is to be incremented each time after the initial population generation class is run.

I have researched this for months now and tried everything I could think of. If someone could direct me or even give me a hint as to how I could save a 2d array so that I can use it for later stages of GA would be of great help.

Thanks

edited: This is the initial population class that has the 2d array bit which creates the teams: each row represents team number and columns are the member ids (i have excluded some code which referred to other classes and instead put that in words):

Comment: You say that you can't store a generated solution in memory temporarily...my first question would be, "how large is this dataset?"  Second, could you provide us some code that specifically does this part?  Third, going from `int` to `Object` isn't a good idea, you'd want to at least bump up to `Integer` if you could see an advantage using the wrapper class.

Comment: Can you please provide details about your implementation? How about information about your "2d" array? How big is it? Why couldn't you save the solution? What did you try?

Comment: i have edited the post to add sample code of the team creation 2d array. i had initially wanted to repeat the group creation 120 times as in 120 Individuals on which selesction, crossover and mutation were to be applied so actually the 2d array is to create 120 different team allocations and save these 120 team allocations in temporary memory

Comment: @Makoto: i tried Integer to Object as well but that didn't work either

Comment: Is that the only location `noTeams` is populated with an integer value?  If it is, the reason your arrays won't work is because you allocate no space in the first dimension.

Comment: Your code does not help much to illustrate your question. What did you try and what is the problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: noTeams is calculated in this class to find out how many rows shld to create. arrays/teams are created just fine. saving thm temporarily is the prob. What i'm tryin to do is create 1 complete team allocation where each member is allocated to 1 team, then create anthr diff team allocation etc then use each of these generated team allocs in fitness eval, selection... stages. I can  write these generated group allocations to a simple txt file bt the prob is as soon as next group alloc is created the previous one is lost i.e. no longer in the memory which i can refer to in the other stages of GA

Comment: @Makoto: sorry but what do you mean by "... you allocate no space in the first dimension". the noTeams is calculated by reading the total number of members from the csv file and then divided by 8 to find the total number of teams that are to be created. Can you kindly explain. Thank you

Comment: On your first edit, that piece of code wasn't there.  I can't infer  the allocation size based on `member.mList.size()`; could you let us know what that is outright, or confirm that it's greater than 1?

Comment: yes, it's always greater than 1. there is a block of code that checks the member list size is always divisible by 8 (so that 8 members in each team) otherwise the file is rejected. It's always about at least 80 members in the list. All of the code is in different classes - a class that reads member data and converts it into double and integer wherever necessary, a class that does the fitness evaluation, a class that writes the final group allocations to a text file and so on... this piece of code above is the initial population class ... if i could somehow just save these groups as objects...

Answer (score 0):

Your issue here is one of architecture. You are creating your population in a separate class without sending it anywhere. You want to wrap your initialization in another class. When I'm writing a new GA I typically do something like this.

```
class GeneticAlgorithm {

  public static int[][] population;
  public static double mutationRate;
  public static double crossoverRate;

  public int[][] initializePopulation //this is where your createTeams method would go
  public int[][] mutation 
  public int[][] crossover

  public void runGA

}
```

This is my basic structure for a GA. In your runGA method you can loop for as many generations as you like, be it based on exit criteria or a static number. Each generation you simply pass your current population into your mutation and crossover functions and it returns you the resulting population. While you are doing all of this your population is safely stored in a variable that can be either saved or outputted upon termination of your GA.

Hope that helps, and best of luck with this.

Comment: i think that is what i was missing earlier. I'll try to run the classes as you suggested and let you know how it worked out (I am about 99% sure this would solve my problem). Thank you so much

Comment: Feel free to post some more info if this doesn't solve your problems. If it does then don't forget to accept the answer.